# Jquery show/hide on image click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I simply want to show a div once you click on a image.The code i have used is below:

```
<td colspan="3" rowspan="7">
        <img title="Vintage Dinner Plate"  onclick="$('dinnerplates').show('fast')"class="masterTooltip" src="images/images/slicevintage_16.jpg" width="110" height="123" alt=""></td>
<div>
<p class="dinnerplates" style="background-color:#69a0d0;">This is my text.This is my text.This is my text.This is my text.This is my text.This is my text.This is my text.</p>
```

Comment: missing `. `  `$('.dinnerplates').show('fast')`

Comment: Could you create a fiddle replicating the problem please.

Comment: Don't use inline JavaScript. jQuery makes it extremely easy to bind event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery selector is missing the prefixed "." before the class name.

It should be:

```
$('.dinnerplates').show('fast')
```

Comment: Maybe it's strange question but have You attached JQuery Library to this document?

Comment: here is a js fiddle i have found it difficult to replicate the problem because it involves images https://jsfiddle.net/7o7xogbt/

Comment: @RebeccaSalliss

When you create a fiddle. You only need to use the part of the code that's causing the issue. As little code as you can whilst still replicating the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/5xs5vewd/

Comment: i figured out what is causing it but not sure how to fix it. I have a sliced image where i have the title show on hover with the class 'masterTooltip' and i think this is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Possibly similar to what you're looking for. Place the script before your `</body>` and provided you have the jQuery library linked in it should work fine.

```
<script>
$(".masterTooltip").click(function() {
    $(".dinnerplates").toggle();
});
</script>
```

UPDATE:
http://jsfiddle.net/5xs5vewd/

Comment: @RebeccaSalliss I've added a fiddle to my answer. It's working there. Have you correctly added jQuery to your page?

Comment: I think it is because on hover i have the title attribute appear

Comment: @RebeccaSalliss I'm not sure if that should have any effect. I don't understand why the above code wouldn't work for you.